# Как отследить завершения процесса программы на С

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Мне необходимо написать программу, которая будет что-либо делать после завершения процесса программы, например калькулятора. То есть вот работаю я с калькулятором, а потом его выключил, соответственно его процесс завершился и моя программа делает заданные мной действия. Как это сделать? Как отследить завершения процесса? Я гуглил и находил советы то что нужно создать отдельный процесс через функцию CreateProcess , а потом использовать WaitForSingleObject или GetExitCodeProcess, но это не то что мне нужно, потому что мне процесс не надо создавать он уже запущен, либо я не совсем понимаю как это работает

Comment: Можно запустить в своей программе таймер и периодически опрашивать работает ли процесс. сначала FindWindow по имени. А потом GetExitCodeProcess. Если возвращает STILL_ACTIVE, то еще приложение работает.

Comment: насчет таймера верно подмечено, у меня в программе он уже реализован для этого, сейчас попробую ваш способ

Comment: Что вам известно про процесс который вы хотите отследить? PID? Имя? hwnd?

Comment: я думаю что это можно узнать, но я не знаю как, в этом и заключается главная проблема, мне сейчас надо сделать так чтобы функция GetExitCodeProcess работала корректно, со 2-ым параметром я разобрался, а с первым не знаю что делать, это который hProcess, мне в него нужно передать как-то имя процесса, например тот же калькулятор, но не знаю как это сделать, потому что не знаю что он принимает и как вообще работает

Comment: я попробовал вставить path до exe файла, это не получилось

Comment: мне необходимо понять как работают эти параметры и функции, то есть необходим либо сам код, либо какая-то статья

Comment: Как найти hProcess по имени процесса - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

Comment: отлично, теперь я нахожу имя процесса, но осталось понять как именно работает функция GetExitCodeProcess, я пробовал следующее:
_if (GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exitCode) == STILL_ACTIVE) ->
    some code;_
Но это не работает как надо, то есть при закрытии процесса код не выполняет свою функцию и проблема не в коде, который идет после if, а именно в неправильном использовании функции GetExitCodeProcess

Comment: HWND h;
 h = FindWindow(TEXT("Notepad"), NULL);

 if (WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE) == WAIT_ABANDONED_0)
 {
  printf("replacing");
 }
я написал код что выше, но это не работает, то есть у меня FindWindow находит окно, но когда я закрываю блокнот, то ничего не происходит , вторая часть кода с  WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE) не делает свою работу

Answer (score -1):

Так работает, если PID известен

```
HANDLE  hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, inProcessID); 

if (NULL != hProcess)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hProcess,INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: За что минус? Напишите, что не так.