# Как отследить завершения процесса программы на С/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Мне необходимо написать программу, которая будет что-либо делать после завершения процесса программы, например калькулятора. То есть вот работаю я с калькулятором, а потом его выключил, соответственно его процесс завершился и моя программа делает заданные мной действия. Как это сделать? Как отследить завершения процесса? Я гуглил и находил советы то что нужно создать отдельный процесс через функцию CreateProcess , а потом использовать WaitForSingleObject или GetExitCodeProcess, но это не то что мне нужно, потому что мне процесс не надо создавать он уже запущен, либо я не совсем понимаю как это работает, помогите пожалуйста очень нужно, любая годная статья или код подойдет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отследить завершения процесса программы на С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192267/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1)

Comment: да это дубликат, потому что на прошлый никто не отвечает!!!!! Хотя я уверен что есть люди которые знают решение или есть хотя бы какие-то материалы

Comment: берете код отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874381/get-a-process-id-in-c-by-name получаете идентификатор искомого процесса, потом OpenProcess() по найденному идентификатору, и потом отслеживайте его состояние. как вы ранее хотели.

Comment: ps тулхел32 уже достаточно древний, есть и другие альтернативы, еще его минус 32х битный процесс не видит 64х битные процессы. но искать лень. я эту проблему решал на .Net через System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName() и потом обходил результат. и мониторил что приложение не повисло. если повисало, то добирался до параметров коммандной строки и пересоздавал процесс по-новой.

Comment: а как отслеживать состояние?

Comment: ну мне то нужно на С/С++, у меня уже есть большой проект и из-за такой мелочи не охото его переписывать

Comment: либо в цикле периодически опрашивать, либо ждать пока WaitForSingleObject вернет WAIT_ABANDONED_0, что означает что хендл открытого вами процесса был уничтожен.

Comment: а есть код с реализацией этих методов?

Comment: есть только для дотнета, но он на си не совсем портируется. там классы немножко выше уровнем чем функции доступные в винапи. не все один в один можно переложить.

Comment: я думаю что для примера пройдет, если можете то отправьте пожалуйста

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115299/discussion-between-yakov-and-s1nger-iwni).